# How can I draw a Sphere with SharpDX *3.0*?

Tags: sharpdx

The SharpDX toolkit has [been abandoned for 3.0 SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit) :(
Unfortunately, we need/are using this for a current Windows 10 project.

What we need to do is create a Sphere object as a surface so we can project on to it. Can anybody lead me to some things (or simply provide said things) that might help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: You can still access source code to it : https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit/blob/master/Source/Toolkit/SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics/GeometricPrimitive.Sphere.cs , so you can grab that code and build a vertex+index buffer manually from the resulting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the toolkit side of things, I'm using this atm for my terrain color map building I'm not sure how it will go if you use it every frame for UI type stuff because the guy that converted it to sharpdx 3 used pinvoke instead of the native fixed call.

https://github.com/tomba/Toolkit

just download as zip, load into VS and remove all the test\projects that fail to load then just build and add a ref to you project like normal.